# How Can I Use Futura Light In Headers Using CSS?

Tags: css, fonts, shopify

I hope this is the correct overflow to ask such a question.

I am currently using this in the latest Dawn theme:

```
.header__menu-item {
font-size: 25px;
font-family: "Futura";
font-weight: 100;
}
```

[image]

However the font-weight has no change on the font itself, it still shows the regular weight. If I change font-weight to 600+, then the font becomes bold. So why does it not show as a lighter variant?

Shopify has the font in their database, but replacing "Futura" with one of the IDs below stops the Futura font from showing completely:

[image]

Is it an issue in my code?